# I need to get information from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, yelp

Here is the result of: `var_dump($response)`:

```
"is_claimed": false, "rating": 4.5, "mobile_url": "http://m.yelp.com/biz/filbert-steps-san-francisco?utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_business\u0026utm_source=NUQkLT4j4VnC6ZR7LI-VWA", "rating_img_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png", "review_count": 208
```

I want to get the rating value, I tried `$response->rating` but I got nothing.

Comment: Start with reading manuals.

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON to me - it should have `{}` curly braces wrapped around it. What do you get from `print_r(json_decode('{' . $response . '}'))`?

Comment: If that's the result of dumping `$response`, could we see the source JSON please? And your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this json first by using `{}` at two sides of the string. After decoding (json_decode) you will got an Array of Objects.

```
$json = '{"is_claimed": false, "rating": 4.5, "mobile_url": "http://m.yelp.com/biz/filbert-steps-san-francisco?utm_campaign=yelp_api\\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_business\\u0026utm_source=NUQkLT4j4VnC6ZR7LI-VWA", "rating_img_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png", "review_count": 208}';
$result = json_decode ($json);

echo $result->rating; // 4.5
```

[Online Check](https://3v4l.org/RTnrr), and let me know is it works for you or not.